# How do I authenticate with txcouchbase?

Tags: python, python-3.x, couchbase

I am connecting to my couchbase server via `bucket = Bucket("couchbase://localhost/users")`, but how do I authenticate, since the server has a username and password?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the ["Hello Couchbase" example in the documentation](https://docs.couchbase.com/python-sdk/current/start-using-sdk.html#hello-couchbase). At the time of writing this answer, that is:

```
from couchbase.cluster import Cluster
from couchbase.cluster import PasswordAuthenticator
cluster = Cluster('couchbase://localhost')
authenticator = PasswordAuthenticator('username', 'password')
cluster.authenticate(authenticator)
cb = cluster.open_bucket('bucket-name')
```

Comment: That is not using txcouchbase. I need the async version. Thanks for the answer, though!